# unable to access 'https://github.com/user name/projectName.git/': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: android, git, android-studio, ssl, clone

I'm trying to clone a project from `Github` but I can't clone it because I have this error
**unable to access : SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain**
I have an access from my network and I have the certifications .

Is there any problem in my `Android Studio` or in my network because I have searched for this many times and I didn't find yet the solution .

**Edit** Here are my Git configuration value after running this command
`git config -l --show-origin`

```
C:\Users\ahmed.taha>git config -l --show-origin
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.required=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig http.sslbackend=openssl
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.autocrlf=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.fscache=true
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.symlinks=false
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig pull.rebase=false
file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig credential.helper=manager
```

Also Here is my `.gitconfig` file

```
[diff "astextplain"]
    textconv = astextplain
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
[http]
    sslBackend = openssl
    sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    fscache = true
    symlinks = false
[pull]
    rebase = false
[credential]
    helper = manager
```